# Telegram id changed to int 64 bit

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

Now the telegram id of the user is in the 64bit range of int. These users are not able to connect with the bot. I have created a bot using telethon and a new 64-bit range telegram id users are getting problems accessing the bot. Old users are comfortable in accessing the bot. Not able to find any solution.
Any solution to fix this issue?
New telegramId range which I found is like 50xxxxxxxx.

Comment: What error are they getting? If you think it's a bug, you may try [reporting an issue to Telethon](https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon/issues/new/choose).

Comment: Not able to see any hit for that user in logs.

Comment: ```@bot.on(events.NewMessage)
async def test(event):
    logger.info('event {event}'.format(event=event))```

Comment: I tried with a simple method but was not able to get anything.

Comment: @SwarnimKumar Can you please write this information into the question? Include the error message and the simple method you've tried

Comment: By updating the telethon library issue has been resolved. ```pip install --upgrade telethon```